# Mysql adding a constraint: force a field to get specific values

Tags: mysql, sql, constraints

I have a simple mysql table with the following attributes: `Name, Surname, Role`.

I want the Role field to get only 2 possible values: `Supervisor` or `Operator` and to result in error when a query tries to insert something different from that 2 values.

For example, i want the following query to return an error:

```
INSERT INTO tablename (name,surname,role) VALUES ('max','power','footballplayer');
```

I tried setting the field `Role` as a `ENUM` or `SET` type but it will just leave the field empty instead of firing and error :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change sql_mode to avoid insert.

```
mysql> create table check_values (
    -> id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    -> name varchar(50),
    -> role enum ('max','power','fp')
    -> )engine = myisam;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> set sql_mode = '';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into check_values (name,role) values ('nick','max');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into check_values (name,role) values ('john','other');
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                   |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'role' at row 1 |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from check_values;
+----+------+------+
| id | name | role |
+----+------+------+
|  1 | nick | max  |
|  2 | john |      |
+----+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> set sql_mode = 'traditional';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into check_values (name,role) values ('frank','other');
ERROR 1265 (01000): Data truncated for column 'role' at row 1
mysql> select * from check_values;
+----+------+------+
| id | name | role |
+----+------+------+
|  1 | nick | max  |
|  2 | john |      |
+----+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: So, i could use the sql_mode switch before every query that need a check... thats exactly what i need for my project. Thank you.

Comment: hi @nick, the last error what type of SQLException would throw for a jdbc driver?

Answer (score 0):

Do you see any error when you use enum as shown here ? 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html

One other approach would be to create a look-up type of table with the allowed roles and create a foreign key constraint from this table to the role table. That would be more appropriate if yu use the check constraint at multiple places or if you have a larger list of values to check against.

MYSQL, I believe, does not support the check constraint directly, if that's what you are looking for. Check these links.

[CHECK constraint in MySQL is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115497/check-constraint-in-mysql-not-working)

[MySQL and Check Constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706231/mysql-and-check-constraints)

[Using Foreign Keys to replace check constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182308/using-foreign-keys-to-replace-check-constraint)

Comment: Thank you i should have looked for answers in this site before asking because that link shows the same problem as mine. Your solution using a foreign key to a "role table" would work but it looks a bit overkill to me in this situation. Thank u again.

Answer (score 0):

use trigger.. to throw the error manually 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html